# Why is my scroll event firing so slowly? Javascript, Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am writing a pretty basic header that will become fixed to the top of the page as a user scrolls.  This is a hard problem to debug because most people have the OPPOSITE problem to what I'm experiencing.  The code I have is working; however, there is a significant delay in the class being applied. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.sticky { 
         position: fixed;
         top: 10px; 
         left: 0px;
         right: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll() {
this.handleScroll();
};

...

handleScroll() {
const header = document.getElementById('stickyBumper');
const distanceToTop = window.scrollY;




if (distanceToTop > 200) {
  if (!header.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    header.classList.add('sticky');
  }
} else {
  header.classList.remove('sticky');
}
```

}

This code is technically working. When I scroll, and the event fires, the class is added and the header becomes "stuck", but the scroll event is only firing once the user has stopped scrolling, and then it takes another second or two to actually add the class. Anyone else have this problem recently? I'm developing in Chrome btw. But I tested this issue in other browsers and getting the same results.

Comment: Just so you know, you are not supposed to access the dom directly when using Angular.

Comment: Just an optimalisation tip: Do not perform the header selector inside the handleScroll callback... it now has to perform that action tens of times per second..

Comment: @Ploppy do you mean that I should be using @ViewChild?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean